# Job with wildcard dependency in IBM LSF killed for being orphaned

Tags: bash, shell, lsf

At work we are using IBM Spectrum LSF 10.1.0.0 build 564512 to submit jobs to a compute cluster.
In a script that I wrote there are different jobs submitted depending on certain parameters that the user can set. Some can be submitted but there are also cases where they are not. The names of these jobs start with a specific string, e.g. "HLA", but have a different ending.
Examples are:

```
HLA_typer1_123456
HLA_typer2_123456
HLA_typer3_123456
```

Now, I want to add a job that should start after all these previous jobs starting with "HLA" are finished (i.e. "done" in job dependencies). Since there are so many possible combinations I wanted to use the wildcard "*" as described in the LSF documentation.

```
-w 'done(HLA*)'
```

However, the job is always immediately killed by LSF after submitting due to being an orphaned job ("TERM_ORPHAN_SYSTEM: orphaned job terminated automatically by LSF").
Since the LSF documentation is without examples and a bit squishy regarding the use of quotation marks in this respect, I tried different quoting, however, giving me the same results.

Has anyone experienced similar and knows what I am doing wrong?
The documentation says following:

> Use double quotes (") around job names that begin with a number. In the job name, specify the wildcard character asterisk (*) at the end of a string, to indicate all jobs whose name begins with the string. For example, if you use jobA* as the job name, it specifies jobs named jobA, jobA1, jobA_test, jobA.log, etc.

Am I misinterpreting something here?

Thanks for any ideas in advance!

Comment: It might not matter, but what is the name of the job that should start when the HLA* jobs are done?

Comment: It‘s a formatting job, so it’s called “formatting_HLA_123456”. Since it doesn’t start with “HLA” this shouldn’t be a problem, right?

Comment: Right, that looks fine.